# Who leaked the news about the merger?

Tags: plot-explanation, limitless

After Eddie Morra comes back from the police station, he finds Carl watching a news report about the secret merger they were about to close.
[image]

Carl is obviously angry and the following dialogue happens:

> Carl: *Have you been talking to anyone?*
>   Eddie: *No I haven't been talking to anyone, Carl. I'm not stupid.*
>   Carl: *I know you're not stupid, Eddie, but don't make the classic smart person's mistake thinking no one's smarter than you.*

Maybe this is completely irrelevant to the plot, but just in case:

**Who leaked the news about Carl van Loon's merger with Atwood?**

Carl accuses Eddie, but we (the viewer) know it wasn't him. Atwood, his wife and Carl all wanted the merger to happen, so they had no motive.

Does the movie give any clue who actually did leak the news and by that stop the merger from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The movie, "Limitless," was closely based on a book written by Alan Glynn, titled, "[The Dark Fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Fields)."  While the names of companies and some details might differ, the explanation for the merger leak is explained fairly clearly in the following passages (289, 299):

[image]

As it wasn't explained in the film version, it is reasonable to attribute the leak to the original source material.  Although, admittidly, Carl was aware of it in the book version (indeed, he was the source).

Comment: Regarding your absolutely unncessary edit, please keep in mind that your answer was only 5 hours old when you wrote that and it isn't the most active question. It is quite a bit premature to call everyone here out as part of a "popularity contest" and not being able to recognize supposedly good answers. It's not that you get tons of upvotes 3 minutes after posting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, from what I remember, it's all been planned by the atwoods to steal his NZT. It all began long before he appeared at the police line up.

I think you are asking the wrong question. The merger is not even a subplot of the movie. The atwoods had a limited resource of NZT and while using NZT, don't forget that they (atwoods) are very smart too. And so, the competition begins. Maybe the merger is part of the plan to lure eddie

Comment: Hi oldage, welcome to the site. Could you please edit your answer and put more information? How did you come to that conclusion? And how would ruining his own multimillion dollar merger help Atwood steal the NZT from Eddie?